# Rendering a very large ResultSet to the screen in JSP

Tags: mysql, jsp, resultset, outputstream, bufferedwriter

I am a beginner programmer, so please be patient! ;-)

I need to display a very large ResultSet (over 15.000 rows) from a `MySQL` query on the screen in the form of a `HTML` table. I am using `JSP` pages to try and accomplish this.

The query itself takes about 0.25s on my `MySQL` server (command-line, via terminal), but over 8 minutes to render on the browser with minimal `HTML`.

If I write the results to a file using something like `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filename),"ISO-8859-1"))`, it is also very fast (1.2s), but it's not what the client wants.

So I guess my question is: is there some way I can use the `OutputStreamWriter` to print the results to the screen instead of writting them to a file? I am assuming that `out.print` is what is causing the huge delays.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share the relevant part of jsp and servlet code you have written?

Comment: it most likely isn't the out.print statements. 15,000 rows will create a large HTML document. Try using paging instead. Where you could show ~500 records at a time on the screen and let the user flip through pages of records.